# How to calculate the expanding mean of all the columns across the DataFrame and add to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the means of all previous rows for each column of the DataFrame and add the calculated mean column to the DataFrame.

I am using a set of nba games data that contains 20+ features (columns) that I am trying to calculate the means for. Example of the dataset is below. (Note. "...." represent rest of the feature columns)

```py
Team TeamPoints OpponentPoints.... TeamPoints_mean  OpponentPoints_mean 
ATL      102        109       ....     nan               nan
ATL      102        92        ....     102               109
ATL      92         94        ....     102               100.5
BOS      119        122       ....     98.67             98.33
BOS      103        96        ....     103.75            104.25
```

Example for calculating two of the columns:

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv('nba.games.stats.csv')
df = dataset

df['Game_mean'] = (df.groupby('Team')['TeamPoints'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().expanding().mean()))
df['TeamPoints_mean'] = (df.groupby('Team')['OpponentsPoints'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().expanding().mean()))
```

Again, the code only calculates the mean and adding the column to the DataFrame one at a time. Is there a way to get the column means and add them to the DataFrame without doing one at a time? For loop? Example of what I am looking for is below.

```py
Team TeamPoints OpponentPoints.... TeamPoints_mean  OpponentPoints_mean ...("..." = mean columns of rest of the feature columns) 
ATL      102        109       ....     nan               nan
ATL      102        92        ....     102               109
ATL      92         94        ....     102               100.5
BOS      119        122       ....     98.67             98.33
BOS      103        96        ....     103.75            104.25
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your dataframe and an example of how your desired output would look like?

Comment: @Jan C 0 See updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**(0) sample input:**

```py
>>> df
       col1      col2      col3
0  1.490977  1.784433  0.852842
1  3.726663  2.845369  7.766797
2  0.042541  1.196383  6.568839
3  4.784911  0.444671  8.019933
4  3.831556  0.902672  0.198920
5  3.672763  2.236639  1.528215
6  0.792616  2.604049  0.373296
7  2.281992  2.563639  1.500008
8  4.096861  0.598854  4.934116
9  3.632607  1.502801  0.241920
```

Then processing:

**(1) side table to get all the means on the side (I didn't find cummulative mean function, so went with `cumsum` + `count`)**

```py
>>> df_side=df.assign(col_temp=1).cumsum()
>>> df_side
        col1       col2       col3  col_temp
0   1.490977   1.784433   0.852842       1.0
1   5.217640   4.629801   8.619638       2.0
2   5.260182   5.826184  15.188477       3.0
3  10.045093   6.270855  23.208410       4.0
4  13.876649   7.173527  23.407330       5.0
5  17.549412   9.410166  24.935545       6.0
6  18.342028  12.014215  25.308841       7.0
7  20.624021  14.577855  26.808849       8.0
8  24.720882  15.176708  31.742965       9.0
9  28.353489  16.679509  31.984885      10.0
>>> for el in df.columns:
...     df_side["{}_mean".format(el)]=df_side[el]/df_side.col_temp
>>> df_side=df_side.drop([el for el in df.columns] + ["col_temp"], axis=1)
>>> df_side
   col1_mean  col2_mean  col3_mean
0   1.490977   1.784433   0.852842
1   2.608820   2.314901   4.309819
2   1.753394   1.942061   5.062826
3   2.511273   1.567714   5.802103
4   2.775330   1.434705   4.681466
5   2.924902   1.568361   4.155924
6   2.620290   1.716316   3.615549
7   2.578003   1.822232   3.351106
8   2.746765   1.686301   3.526996
9   2.835349   1.667951   3.198489
```

**(2) joining back, on index:**

```py
>>> df_final=df.join(df_side)
>>> df_final
       col1      col2      col3  col1_mean  col2_mean  col3_mean
0  1.490977  1.784433  0.852842   1.490977   1.784433   0.852842
1  3.726663  2.845369  7.766797   2.608820   2.314901   4.309819
2  0.042541  1.196383  6.568839   1.753394   1.942061   5.062826
3  4.784911  0.444671  8.019933   2.511273   1.567714   5.802103
4  3.831556  0.902672  0.198920   2.775330   1.434705   4.681466
5  3.672763  2.236639  1.528215   2.924902   1.568361   4.155924
6  0.792616  2.604049  0.373296   2.620290   1.716316   3.615549
7  2.281992  2.563639  1.500008   2.578003   1.822232   3.351106
8  4.096861  0.598854  4.934116   2.746765   1.686301   3.526996
9  3.632607  1.502801  0.241920   2.835349   1.667951   3.198489
```

Comment: I updated with an example of the dataset and expected result. The problem is I have 20+ columns and want to calculate the mean of each column, via expanding(), and attached them to the DataFrame without listing each of them manually.

Comment: I updated my code - now it's input-agnostic (assuming your input will have numeric columns only, which you can achieve, if you will group by ```Team``` and sum all the values - ```df=df.groupby("Team").sum()```)

Comment: I do have some categorical columns. Is there an if statement that I can use to bypass them?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want grouping just replace first line of point (1) with: ```df_side=df.drop([<list of categorical columns>], axis=1).assign(col_temp=1).cumsum()```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to calculate the means of all previous rows for each column of the DataFrame

To get all of the columns, you can do:

```
df_means = df.join(df.cumsum()/
                     df.applymap(lambda x:1).cumsum(),
                   r_suffix = "_mean")
```

However, if `Team` is a column rather the index, you'd want to get rid of it:

```
df_data = df.drop('Teams', axis=1)
df_means = df.join(df_data.cumsum()/
                     df_data.applymap(lambda x:1).cumsum(),
                   r_suffix = "_mean")
```

You could also do

```
import numpy as np
df_data = df[[col for col in df.columns 
              if np.issubdtype(df[col],np.number)]]
```

Or manually define a list of columns that you want to take the mean of, `cols_for_mean`, and then do

```
df_data = df[cols_for_mean]
```